# JavaFx2: Nullpointer in AbstractTimer

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

Im getting the following `NullpointerException`, when i update a lot of JavaFX-charts:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer.timePulseImpl(AbstractMasterTimer.java:366)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer$MainLoop.run(AbstractMasterTimer.java:289)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:459)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$9.run(QuantumToolkit.java:332)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

and the JavaFX-Thread is going to crash completeley.

Im using JavaFX from a Swing based Application to show around 20 charts, who are updatet with new data every 10 seconds. 2 of them are updatet every 2 seconds.
Every update is running in a Platform.runLater(). So 20 runLaters every 10 seconds.
I have read, that the JavaFX-Thread or EventQueue will be swamped with too many runLater's.
So i reduced the calls of PLatform.runLater to 3 every 10 seconds and everything was running fine.But then i had to redo the 20 calls again, because we can't use Java 1.7 from the side, where i could gather all updates in 3 runLater.
Now we are getting the Nullpointer again.
Is the Nullpointer caused by overloading the JavaFX-Thread? Or do i have another Problem here?

Here is a example for a update method that is running in a Platform.runlater:

```
public static void updateBarChart(final ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> oldData, final Map<String, Number> newData) {

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            logger.trace("ChartUpdater.updateBarChart");
            Series<String, Number> series = oldData.get(0);
            ObservableList<Data<String, Number>> listData = series.getData();

            Set<String> keySet = newData.keySet();

            outer: for (String string : keySet) {
                boolean exists = false;

                for (Data<String, Number> data : listData) {
                    if (data.getXValue().equals(string)) {
                        data.setYValue(newData.get(string));

                        Tooltip.install(data.getNode(), new Tooltip(data.getYValue().toString()));
                        exists = true;
                        continue outer;
                    }
                }

                if (!exists) {
                    final Data<String, Number> data = new BarChart.Data<String, Number>(string, newData.get(string));
                    series.getData().add(data);
                    displayLabelForData(data);
                }
            }

            double scale = 1.0;

            if (series.getData().size() == 2) {
                scale = 0.5d;
            }
            else if (series.getData().size() == 1) {
                scale = 0.2d;
            }

            if (scale != 1.0d) {
                for (Data<String, Number> dataObeject : series.getData()) {
                    dataObeject.getNode().setScaleX(scale);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: threading issues in mixing swing/fx can be nasty and are highly dependent on context (in my limited experience with fx) Anyway, please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem so somebody can try to track it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the source of the problem.
Beside the charts i used third party Gauges.
These were causing the Nullpointer. So i kicked them, and everything is running fine now.

Answer (score 0):

How about updating your JavaFX? I'm not sure for which versions but AbstractMasterTimer and a lot of other sources have already changed.